# Prediction of DNA binding motif from sequence/structure of TF/regulator protein?

Tags: machine-learning, docking, motifs

Do you know if it is actually possible to predict with good accuracy a DNA binding motif from only the sequence/structure of the DNA-binding protein?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question looks like it's too general to be useful for asking or answering; please frame your question around a specific problem that you're having, especially including detail about the nature of the DNA binding motif that you're interested in.

Comment: Find papers....

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6153143/